# Is it possible to dynamically set the content of the Twilio phone call

Tags: twilio

we are developing a mobile (iOS/Android) application through which the user can send an automatic Twilio phone call (using Parse Cloud Code) to a number of her/his choice. Is it possible to dynamically set the content of the phone call from the client (like one can do with SMS’s by passing a string as a variable)? From the examples in the Parse/Twilio documentation it seems that this is not the case and one can only set in advance different texts at different URL’s and choose between them. Is it so?

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can dynamically set phone call content from a single URL by adding URL parameters to the URL you set for the phone call. So, if, for example, you created a call like so:

```
client.makeCall({
  to: NUMBER,
  from: YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER,
  url: 'http://example.com/call/?name=Phil'
}, function(err, responseData) {
  // call is made
});
```

Then you can use the `name` parameter in the callback to alter the response. Here's an example route in express:

```
app.post('/call', function(req, res) {
  responseText = "Hello " + req.query.name;
  res.send("<Response><Say>" + responseText + "</Say></Response>");
});
```

I hope this helps, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Sorry @pkliang, I meant `query` rather than `params`. I always get confused over the different parameters in Express.